# How do I specify the JDK for a GlassFish domain?

Tags: java, glassfish

I've got GlassFish 2.1.1 installed. I have a 1.5 and a 1.6 JDK installed. Even though my JAVA_HOME variable is set to the 1.5 version (and both "java -version" and "javac -version" display 1.5), whenever I start my glassfish domain it always states at the top of the log that its using version 1.6. How can I override this?

```
Starting Domain domain2, please wait.
04-May-2012 08:38:47 com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.launch.ASLauncher buildCommand
INFO:
C:/Dev/jdk/1.6/1.6.0_19\bin\java
```

Comment: The installer picks a suitable JDK.  If you want a simple solution, reinstalling using the installer can do it.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Can you point to a Glassfish installer? (e.g. https://glassfish.org/download has no installers)

Comment: @IanBoyd this was 10 years ago where glassfish was an actual, cared for product too.

Comment: Twas a simpler time...

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Here you can find how to set path to JDK for Glassfish: http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/fixing-glassfish-jdk-path-problem-solved

Check

```
glassfish\config\asenv.bat
```

where java path is configured

```
REM set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_04\jre/..
set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_16
```

Comment: Not enough for GF 4.1.1 in my experience, see my answer below.

Comment: Terrific! Works great in glassfish 4.1.2!

Comment: in glassfish 5.0.0 there is no such var AS_JAVA setted. But I add it at the end of the asenv.bat file. That solved my problem

Answer (score 13):

Adding the actual content from dbf's link in order to keep the solution within stackoverflow.

> It turns out that when I first installed Glassfish on my Windows
>   system I had JDK 6 installed, and recently I had to downgrade to JDK 5
>   to compile some code for another project.
>
> Apparently when Glassfish is installed it hard-codes its reference to
>   your JDK location, so to fix this problem I ended up having to edit a
>   file named asenv.bat. In short, I edited this file:

```
C:\glassfish\config\asenv.bat:
```

> and I commented out the reference to JDK 6 and added a new reference
>   to JDK 5, like this:

```
REM set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_04\jre/..
set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_16
```

Although the path doesn't appear to be case sensitive, I've spent hours debugging an issue around **JMS Destination object not found** due to my replacement path's case being incorrect.

Answer (score 10):

I'm working on a Mac, OSX 10.9.  I recently had to update my JDK to 1.7 for some VPN software. The application I'm working runs on JDK 1.6, so a GlassFish had to run with JDK 1.6.  It took a minute to iron this out, but here's how it went for me.  I work with the NetBeans IDE by the way.

1. My GlssFish configuration file

   `/Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-3.1.2.2/glassfish/config/asenv.conf`
2. Path to JDK 1.6

   `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home`
3. I added the following line to the bottom of my `asenv.conf` file

   `AS_JAVA=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home`

Comment: @TowfikAlrazihi - I haven't done any Java development for about 2 years now, I no longer own the machine I did this work on, so I can't be much help here.  Asking dumb questions: 1. You did restart Glassfish? 2. `which java` informed the path you used for your `AS_JAVA` configuration in the `asenv.conf` file?

Comment: please refer to my answer below

Answer (score 7):

According to the GF Administration Guide:

> For a valid JVM installation, locations are checked in the following order:
>   a. domain.xml (java-home inside java-config) 
>   b. asenv.conf (setting AS_JAVA="path to java home")

I had to add *both* these settings to make it work. Otherwise 'asadmin stop-domain domain1' wouldn't work. I guess that GF uses a. and asadmin uses b.

(On Windows: b. asenv.bat)

Comment: Setting java-home in domain.xml is not standard and AFAIK not in vanilla installations.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem in my IntelliJ 17 after adding fresh glassfish 4.1.

I had set my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable as follow:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\
```

Then opened `%GLASSFISH_HOME%\glassfish\config\asenv.bat`

And just added and the end of the file:

`set AS_JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%`

Then Glassfish started without problems.

Answer (score 5):

Similar error with Glassfish 4.0 and several JDK installed:

```
SEVERE: GlassFish requires JDK 7, you are using JDK version 6.
```

There is no AS_JAVA reference in "C:\glassfish\config\asenv.bat" by default. After adding manually

```
set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
```

it works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the JAVA_HOME variable was set an installed jre.

An alternative to setting the AS_JAVA variable is to set JAVA_HOME environment variable to the jdk (i.e. /usr/local/jdk1.7.0.51).

Answer (score 1):

ERROR MESSAGE :

.....
    PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
    -Source 1.5 does not support the diamond operator
      (please use -source version 7 or higher to enable the diamond operator)

Solution

On MAC : go to

- /Users/username/GlassFish_Server/glassfish/domains/domain2/config
- open  the default_web.xml file
- find the  jsp
- add

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

In Linux file system , Edit below file as this steps

Path - **/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/config**

File Name - **asenv.conf**

Add the JAVA HOME path as below to the end of file.

**AS_JAVA=/opt/jdk1.8.0_201**

Now start the glassfish server.