# specify the jdk for a glassfish domain Linux

Tags: java, linux, glassfish

I already know that similar answer has been written ([How do I specify the jdk for a glassfish domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444959/how-do-i-specify-the-jdk-for-a-glassfish-domain)) but it was for windows, my system is linux and i cant'resolve even if I tried the suggested solution...
i've Glassfish 3 installed in TurnKey Debian. I have JDK a 1.7 installed in /opt/jdk1.7.0_21
 JAVA_HOME points to /opt/java which is a simbolic link for /opt/jdk1.7.0_21
My asenv.conf:

```
AS_IMQ_LIB="../../mq/lib"
AS_IMQ_BIN="../../mq/bin"
AS_CONFIG="../config"
AS_INSTALL=".."
AS_DEF_DOMAINS_PATH="../domains"
AS_DEF_NODES_PATH="../nodes"
AS_DERBY_INSTALL="../../javadb"
AS_JAVA="/opt/jdk7"
```

/opt/jdk7 is another ln that points to /opt/jdk1.7.0_21
When i try to start glassfish (single domain, domain 1) it says:
/bin/java: not found

what is wrong??

Answer (score 0):

/opt/jdk7/bin/java (or /opt/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java ) should point to the java executable. If that doesn't exist, modifying AS_JAVA to:

```
AS_JAVA="/opt/jdk7/jre/"
```

or

```
AS_JAVA="/opt/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/"
```

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work... setting 
AS_JAVA="/opt/jdk7/jre/" say 
/bin/java: not foundjre/ setting AS_JAVA="/opt/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/" say  /bin/java: not found7.0_21/jre/

Comment: What are the contents of your /opt/jdk7/ folder?

Comment: /opt/jdk7 is simply a symbolic link that points to /opt/jdk1.7.0_21, contents of /opt/jdk1.7.0_21 is

`COPYRIGHT
LICENSE
README.html
THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt
THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
bin
db
include
jre
lib
man
release
src.zip`

Comment: That should work. My glassfish is configured like this and it works fine: AS_JAVA=/usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_45