# "application need 1.6 or higher version of java" error while installing glassfish server?

Tags: java, glassfish

I have downloaded `glassfish server 3.1` and i have installed `java 1.7`, but while installing `glassfish` server I have the error below:

[image]

My java version is:

```
C:\Users\viksa>java -version
java version "1.7.0_04"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b22)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the tour, and read through the help center.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to your glassfish download location:

   `C:\Users\J Balakrishna\Downloads`
2. Take your Java installed location:

   `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112`
3. Run:

   `C:\Users\J Balakrishna\Downloads>glassfish-3.1.2-windows.exe -j "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112"`

Comment: I did same way as you mentioned. But no luck, I have downloaded and installed Java 9 SDk prior to installation of GF 3.1

Answer (score 1):

Please check "[How do I specify the jdk for a glassfish domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444959/how-do-i-specify-the-jdk-for-a-glassfish-domain)".I think You can get similar ways just like adding JDK to asenv.bat.

Answer (score 0):

please check the environment variable settings, it seems its referring to an old instance of JRE which is also present in the machine.

Check the PATH variable.

Comment: i have checked PATH variable but there is only path for jre and jkd, can you please suggest another approach

Answer (score 0):

check your JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Finally, follow the instructions on the last line of that popup:

`ogs-3.1.2.2-windows.exe -j \path\to\where\your\java\is`

Answer (score 0):

Download and install java runtime enviornment 1.6 ... its the requirement for JRE and not JDK