# GlassFish requires Java SE version 6. Your JDK is version 0 (Mac)

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, glassfish

I'm doing a project in IntelliJ with GlassFish and it throws this error:

> GlassFish requires Java SE version 6.  Your JDK is version 0.

I ran the `glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain` command in a terminal but still get the same error.

I do have Java SE installed, SDK version 8u152 (I checked on Java Panel). Also, I don't know why it searches for jdk 9.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of things that could simply have been posted as text.

Comment: You project default  SDK is set to Java9.  That is why intelliJ starts java command line along with JDK9 path.

Comment: so, how was the issue solved @Luis Frediani??

Comment: I suspect you are using software that is so old that it does not know about the change in how later versions of Java report their version number. I suggest upgrading to a later version of Glassfish or downgrading your Java to an older version. You may have multiple JVMs installed as well and are unaware of which is being used.

Answer (score 3):

Which me, open `asenv.conf` in `PATH_TO_YOUR_GLASSFISH/glassfish/config` folder, go to end of lines and add `set AS_JAVA=/PATH_TO_YOUR_JAVA/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-YOUR-VERSION.jdk`

Answer (score 2):

For me java home was good, the only issue was that the version was not matching up.

Open “glassfish -> config -> asenv.conf”.
Add the line AS_JAVA=PATH_TO_YOUR_JDK_DIRECTORY

The only stuff needs to be kept in mind is AS_JAVA=**PATH_TO_YOUR_JDK_DIRECTORY** should exactly match with the jdk version you mentioned in your intellij.

Now ->

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40 is mentioned in intellij... file-> SDK's
set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40 is mentioned in **glassfish -> config -> asenv.conf**

Comment: Adding AS_JAVA line worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

I tried all these approaches and none worked for me.

All answers talk about going to folder `PATH_TO_YOUR_GLASSFISH/glassfish/config` and then editing `asenv.conf`.

Editing that file didn't have have any effect.

I did go to that folder but ended up editing `asenv.bat`.

I literally added this to the end: `set AS_JAVA=../../../../Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_261`

The generic instruction would be: `set AS_JAVA=PATH_TO_YOUR_JDK`

Note: the `asenv.conf` file has quotes around values, `asenv.bat` does not.

I finally tracked the answer down from this question:

[How do I specify the JDK for a GlassFish domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444959/how-do-i-specify-the-jdk-for-a-glassfish-domain)

Comment: Why did everyone answer `Program Files` to a question that says `MacBook`

Answer (score 1):

Go to folder '..\GlassFish-4.1.2\glassfish4\glassfish\config'.
Open in Notepad: asenv.bat
Add in end row:
set AS_JAVA=....\Java\jdk1.8.0_291

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was completely unrelated to IntelliJ setup and `JAVA_HOME` was pointing to correct path (version 1.8).

Despite that, runtime of java version 9 was actually used, so I uninstalled JRE 9.
Left JDK9, since removing the runtime was enough as a quick fix.