# Intellij 2019.2: GlassFish requires Java SE version 6. Your JDK is version 0

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, glassfish, glassfish-4

I'm working with IntelliJ 2019.2 and cannot start the Glassfish Server 4.1.2 (Full Platform). I've found some solution proposals for this error, but none of them worked for me, e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47490645/glassfish-requires-java-se-version-6-your-jdk-is-version-0-mac) or [this article](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-fix-the-GlassFish-requires-Java-SE-version-6-Your-JDK-is-version-0-problem).

**Output**

```
C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat start-domain domain1
GlassFish requires Java SE version 6.  Your JDK is version 0
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.ejb-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.servlet-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.servlet.jsp-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\acc-config.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\admin-cli.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\admin-core.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\admin-util.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\amx-core.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\amx-javaee.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\annotation-framework.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\ant.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\antlr-repackaged.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\aopalliance-repackaged.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\api-exporter.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\appclient-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\appclient-server-core.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\appclient.security.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\asm-all-repackaged.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\asm-all.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.configadmin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.eventadmin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.fileinstall.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.gogo.command.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.scr.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-cdi.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-ee-resources.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-ejb-container.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-http.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-javaee-base.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-jdbc.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-jpa.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-jta.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-web-container.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\backup.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\bean-validator-cdi.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\bean-validator.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\cdi-api-fragment.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\cdi-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\class-model.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\cluster-admin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\cluster-common.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\cluster-ssh.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\cmp-ejb-mapping.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\cmp-enhancer.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\cmp-generator-database.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\cmp-internal-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\cmp-model.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\cmp-support-ejb.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\cmp-support-sqlstore.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\cmp-utility.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\com.ibm.jbatch.container.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\com.ibm.jbatch.spi.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\common-util.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\concurrent-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\concurrent-impl.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\config-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\config-types.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\connectors-admin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\connectors-inbound-runtime.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\connectors-internal-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\connectors-runtime.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\console-cluster-plugin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\console-common-full-plugin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\console-common.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\console-community-branding-plugin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\console-concurrent-plugin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\console-corba-plugin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\console-ejb-lite-plugin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\console-ejb-plugin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\console-jca-plugin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\console-jdbc-plugin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\console-jms-plugin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\console-jts-plugin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\console-plugin-service.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\console-updatecenter-plugin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\console-web-plugin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\container-common.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\dataprovider.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\dbschema-repackaged.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\deployment-admin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\deployment-autodeploy.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\deployment-client.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\deployment-common.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\deployment-javaee-core.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\deployment-javaee-full.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\dol.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\ejb-client.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\ejb-container.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\ejb-full-container.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\ejb-internal-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\ejb.security.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\endorsed\javax.annotation-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\endorsed\jaxb-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\endorsed\webservices-api-osgi.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\entitybean-container.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\flashlight-extra-jdk-packages.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\flashlight-framework.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\gf-admingui-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\gf-client-module.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\gf-connectors-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\gf-ejb-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\gf-jms-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\gf-jms-injection.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\gf-jpa-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\gf-load-balancer-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\gf-restadmin-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\gf-web-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\gf-weld-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-batch-commands.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-batch-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-corba-csiv2-idl.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-corba-internal-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-corba-omgapi.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-corba-orb.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-ee-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-extra-jre-packages.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-grizzly-extra-all.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-mbeanserver.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-naming.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-oracle-jdbc-driver-packages.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-registration.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\glassfish.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\gmbal.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\gms-adapter.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\gms-bootstrap.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\guava.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\ha-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\ha-file-store.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\ha-shoal-cache-bootstrap.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\ha-shoal-cache-store.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\hk2-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\hk2-config.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\hk2-core.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\hk2-locator.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\hk2-runlevel.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\hk2-utils.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\hk2.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\inmemory.jacc.provider.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\internal-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\j-interop-repackaged.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jackson-annotations.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jackson-core.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jackson-databind.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jackson-jaxrs-base.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jackson-jaxrs-json-provider.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jaspic.provider.framework.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javaee-kernel.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javamail-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javamail-runtime.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javassist.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.batch-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.el.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.enterprise.concurrent-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.enterprise.concurrent.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.enterprise.deploy-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.faces.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.inject.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.interceptor-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.jms-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.json.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.mail.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.management.j2ee-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.persistence.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.resource-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.security.auth.message-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.security.jacc-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.servlet.jsp.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.transaction-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.websocket-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.ws.rs-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.xml.registry-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.xml.rpc-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jaxb-extra-osgi.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jaxb-osgi.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jboss-logging.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jdbc-admin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jdbc-config.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jdbc-runtime.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-bean-validation.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-cdi1x-servlet.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-cdi1x-transaction.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-cdi1x.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-client.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-common.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-container-grizzly2-http.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-container-servlet-core.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-container-servlet.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-entity-filtering.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-gf-ejb.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-guava.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-jaxb.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-json-jackson.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-json-jettison.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-json-processing.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-moxy.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-multipart.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-sse.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-mvc-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-mvc-jsp.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-mvc.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jersey-server.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jettison.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jms-admin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jms-core.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jmxremote_optional-repackaged.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jpa-container.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jsf-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jsftemplating.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jsonp-jaxrs.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jspcaching-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jsr109-impl.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jstl-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jta.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\jts.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\kernel.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\launcher.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\ldapbp-repackaged.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\libpam4j-repackaged.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\load-balancer-admin.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\logging.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\management-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\metro-glue.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\mimepull.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\monitoring-core.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\nucleus-grizzly-all.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\nucleus-resources.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\orb-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\orb-enabler.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\orb-iiop.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.antlr.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.asm.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.core.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.dbws.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.oracle.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\osgi-adapter.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\osgi-cli-remote.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\osgi-container.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\osgi-jpa-extension.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\osgi-resource-locator.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\persistence-common.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\pfl-asm.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\pfl-basic-tools.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\pfl-basic.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\pfl-dynamic.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\pfl-tf-tools.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\pfl-tf.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\pkg-client.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\registration-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\registration-impl.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\resources-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\resources-runtime.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\rest-client.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\rest-service.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\scattered-archive-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\schema2beans-repackaged.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\security-ee.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\security-services.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\security.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\shoal-cache.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\shoal-gms-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\shoal-gms-impl.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\simple-glassfish-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\soap-tcp.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\ssl-impl.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\stats77.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\stax2-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\transaction-internal-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\trilead-ssh2-repackaged.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\tyrus-client.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\tyrus-container-glassfish-cdi.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\tyrus-container-glassfish-ejb.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\tyrus-container-grizzly-client.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\tyrus-container-servlet.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\tyrus-core.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\tyrus-server.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\tyrus-spi.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\war-util.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\web-cli.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\web-core.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\web-embed-api.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\web-glue.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\web-gui-plugin-common.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\web-ha.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\web-naming.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\web-sse.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\websecurity.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\webservices-connector.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\webservices-extra-jdk-packages.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\webservices-osgi.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\webservices.security.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\weld-integration-fragment.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\weld-integration.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\weld-osgi-bundle.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\woodstox-core-asl.jar;C:\workspace\resources\server\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\work-management.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\plugins\JavaEE\lib\javaee-impl.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\lib\platform-api.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\lib\util.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2\plugins\Glassfish\lib\specifics\glassfish3.1-specifics.jar" com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 58993 com.intellij.javaee.oss.glassfish.agent.Glassfish31Agent
Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 8080
```

- It already worked once, but I had to change my workstation and reinstall IntelliJ
- I also updated my JDK, it is still version 8, but now another u number (8u221, I don't know which version I used before)
- The Application Server settings in IntelliJ are correct
- The Glassfish logs are empty
- My JAVA_HOME is set correctly (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221)
- I added %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the PATH variable.
- I'm able to start the server over the cmd (asadmin.bat start-domain domain1)
- Ensured that correct SDK is set in IntelliJ (Project Structure -> Platform Settings)
- Tried different Java Compiler Settings (IntelliJ Settings), e.g. changed Project Byte Code version to 6 instead of 8.
- Adding the line AS_JAVA=MY_JDK_DIRECTORY did not help
- Reinstalling Glassfish did not help
- Glassfish Plugin in IntelliJ is enabled (default)

  ```
  java -version
  java version "1.8.0_221"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
  ```

I don't know what to do anymore, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of your Injellij double shift (press shift twice) to open the search and type in JDK. Under actions click on switch boot JDK and make sure you have one there if not select one and then click save and restart. hope this works and helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! How did you know?

Comment: I went into Intellij and searched for anything that had SDK or JDK and i said double shift because i think its better to get to search with that seems faster for me. and I'm glad i could help!!!

Answer (score 2):

The root case of the issue is [logged here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-218032).

Windows launcher prepends `PATH` with JetBrains Runtime `bin` directory in order to load certain DLLs without issues. It turned out to be not the best solution and we are working to address it in a different way.

`asadmin.bat` uses the first `java.exe` from `PATH`. It doesn't try to detect it via `JAVA_HOME`. Therefore the workaround for now is to switch IntelliJ IDEA boot JDK to JBR8 per [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879) or start IntelliJ IDEA using `idea.bat` instead of `idea64.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried changing the IntelliJ configuration but no luck.

I tried starting the server from the command line using: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish4\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat" start-domain --debug domain1`.

I still got the error from the command line.

I had to edit the following file:

`PATH_TO_YOUR_GLASSFISH/glassfish/config/asenv.bat`

Literally: `C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish4\glassfish\config\asenv.bat`

I added the following to the end: `set AS_JAVA=PATH_TO_YOUR_JDK`

Literally: `set AS_JAVA=../../../../Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_261`

I finally tracked the answer down from this question:

[How do I specify the JDK for a GlassFish domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444959/how-do-i-specify-the-jdk-for-a-glassfish-domain)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on linux host installed with Java 10.

Settings JAVA_HOME, AS_JAVA or updating asenv.conf does not solve the problem. Event checking current active JDK .

It seems that Glassfish supports JDK6 only. It does not work with JDK10 or JDK8.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every suggestion her but it did not work. For me problem was that my Glassfish configration was not pointing to correct directory. It was pointing to C:\payara5\glassfish. I changes it to C:\payara5 and it worked.