# Multiple Java versions on Mac and Glassfish Error

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

I am trying to run Java on Glassfish server (JSP) using Netbeans as the IDE. When I try to run I am getting an error that Glassfish cannot be started with JDK 12 (Default).

When I type "java -version" in terminal, I get JAVA 12 as the installed version

When I check Java version in System Preferences it says I have Java version 8 ...

How do I make Netbeans refer to Java 8 and not to Java 12?

Should I remove Java 12 altogether?

Comment: If you do not use the JDK12 at all, you can uninstall it. Otherwise you can run Glassfish with a specific java version. Check this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444959/how-do-i-specify-the-jdk-for-a-glassfish-domain

Comment: Can you switch java 12 for java 8 in your path?